# ant java jar without main class

Tags: java, ant, jar

I need to ant java jar that is execute a jar file that has been created without Main-Class attribute. 
The Documentation of ant Java task says that the jar file must have a Main-Class manifest.
 Is there any way?

Sorry for Typos earlier

Part of build.xml to create JAR - without Main-Class

```
<target name = "createJar" depends = "javac">
<jar destfile = "./sampleJar.jar"
     basedir = "build/classes"
 />
</target>
```

Now i want to

```
<java jar />
```

this jar file by passing classname as some kind of arguments. Possible?

Comment: Attach your `build.xml` file please

Comment: What does "ant a jar file" mean? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<java classname="my.package.ClassWithMain">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="sampleJar.jar"/>
       <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
     </classpath>
</java>
```

`my.package.ClassWithMain` is the fully qualified name of the class with a main method, the classpath should point to the jar containing the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running the jar file you would instruct Ant's `java` task to use the jar file as classpath and run the main class directly. E. g. using a task like the following, taken from the [documentation of the `java` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

```
 <java classname="test.Main">
   <classpath>
     <pathelement location="./sampleJar.jar"/>
     <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
   </classpath>
 </java>
```

Of course, you will have to adjust the main class'es name `test.Main` for your use case.

Comment: Ha, I was five seconds faster! ;-)

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski Yep, I didn't see your answer until I had already posted mine ;) I'll +1 yours.